# Adding Even Parity bit and 2 stop bits to a 8 bits std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

Here is the code: In this the calculation for the parity bit is not done. Parity bit can be calculated using the for loop but is there any other short or better way to calculate the even parity bit in this context. 
Is it somehow possible to use arrays instead of 8 TxDataReg std_logic_vector considering that after making arrays I wish to access bit by bit the array of 8 signals of 8 bits, bit by bit for sending the data in the uart_tx port?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Uart_tx is
    Port ( 
            tx_clk_in    : in  STD_LOGIC;
            reset        : in  STD_LOGIC;
            tx           : out STD_LOGIC;
            Rx_Data_in   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0)

          );
end Uart_tx;

architecture Behavioral of Uart_tx is   

signal  Tx_Data      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(63 downto 0)    := "00000000";

signal DataByteArray1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray3 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray4 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray5 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray6 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray7 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal DataByteArray8 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");

signal TxDataReg1 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg2 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg3 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg4 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg5 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg6 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg7 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");
signal TxDataReg8 : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0) := (others => "00000000");


signal count : unsigned(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal one_bit : std_logic := '0';

begin

Tx_Data <= Rx_Data_in;

DataByteArray1 <= Rx_Data_in(7 downto 0);
DataByteArray2 <= Rx_Data_in(15 downto 8);
DataByteArray3 <= Rx_Data_in(23 downto 16);
DataByteArray4 <= Rx_Data_in(31 downto 24);
DataByteArray5 <= Rx_Data_in(39 downto 32);
DataByteArray6 <= Rx_Data_in(47 downto 40);
DataByteArray7 <= Rx_Data_in(55 downto 48);
DataByteArray8 <= Rx_Data_in(63 downto 56);



Process (tx_clk_in)
begin 

-- Calculate the parity bit 
for i in 0 to 7 loop 

one_bit = DataByteArray1(i);
if one_bit = '1' then 
count = count + 1;
end if;
end loop;
-- For all the registers,one even parity & two stop bits I am trying to add in the end
if count mod 2 = 0 then 
TxDataReg1 <= DataByteArray1&'0'&'11';  -- I am not so sure that this works or not
count <= "000";
else 
TxDataReg1 <= DataByteArray1&'1'&'11';
count <= "000";
end if;

-- Send the uart data from TxDataReg1,TxDataReg2 ...
-- etc.
end process;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

This UART would be much easier to understand if you created a State Machine.  State Machines give your code an organized flow.  The flow just makes more sense.  In VHDL you can create `enumerated states` which means that you can give them names.  I recommend this approach.

It's much harder to keep counters throughout your design to know exactly when to insert the parity bit or when to insert the 2 stop bits in your UART design.  If you have a nice state machine it will make much more sense to you I believe.  This is especially recommended for anyone new at FPGAs.

When you calculate your parity, just keep a running parity bit that gets an `XOR` with the outgoing serial data.  Create a state to insert your parity bit at the correct time, then insert your two stop bits.

For an example of this, look at this [UART VHDL Code](http://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/module-uart-serial-port-rs232.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would second the suggestion to reorganize this to use an FSM that works on just a byte at a time. Then you will have a general purpose async. TX entity that another controller can send bytes to as needed.

As to managing your data. It would be simpler if you created an array of byte arrays:

```vhdl
subtype byte is std_logic_Vector(7 downto 0);

type byte_array is array(natural range <>) of byte;

signal data_byte_array : byte_array(1 to 8);
signal byte_index : unsigned(2 downto 0);
...
-- Select the current byte
cur_byte <= data_byte_array(to_integer(byte_index));
```

The subtype isn't strictly necessary but it is a good habit to use for common data types to save you from littering your code with so many hard-coded array bounds.

For calculating parity you need to adopt the hardware mindset of implementing logic gates rather than the software approach of counting set bits. Parity calculation boils down to an XOR-reduce operation applied to all the bits in your vector. For even parity, you XOR all bits. For odd parity, you XOR all bits and invert the result. Because XOR is equivalent to a controlled inversion you can select the parity type by setting an initial state and performing one extra XOR to get the optional inversion based on your desire for odd or even.

```vhdl
-- Any VHDL:
variable parity : std_logic;

parity := '0'; -- Set to '1' to get odd parity
for i in cur_byte'range loop
  parity := parity xor cur_byte(i);
end loop;

-- VHDL-2002
use ieee.reduce_pack.xor_reduce;
parity := xor_reduce(cur_byte);

-- VHDL-2008
parity := xor cur_byte;
```

In synthesis these approaches all boil down to the same logic so any of them is fine for all practical purposes. This is an explicitly parallel operation and you don't have to step through the byte bitwise with the unneeded overhead of a counter.

You have committed a cardinal sin of mixing the non-standard Synopsys libraries std_logic_unsigned, _signed, and _arith with the true standard numeric library numeric_std. Never mix them in the same file and, better yet, never use the Synopsys libraries at all. They are a historical aberration best forgotten.

Comment: And is that part fine, where I am making the TX-Registers of 11 bits so that I can put there values on the tx port? Using the concatenation operator. Is some state machine sort of things possible.. I am not good in applying state machine concept

Comment: subtype isn't necessary means can I declare type byte is std_logic_Vector(7 downto 0); ? and again make a type byte_array is array(natural range <>) of byte; ?

Comment: Yes you could do that because subtypes are "closely related" to their parent type. Array subtypes are freely interchangeable when their lengths match.